# How to conditionally align text with ngStyle

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been trying to conditionally align some text with ngStyle, but unsuccessfully thus far.

Here's the code I've developed so far:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'display':totalRegisters<=10 ? 'inline-block; text-align: right; width: 100%' : null}">
```

If someone can help out, I'd much appreciate it

Comment: Is using a class instead of inline css acceptable?

Comment: I don't think there would be any issues with using class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `ngClass`.

1. Place your alignment style into css class
2. Use `ngClass`, example : `<div [ngClass]="{'my-class': totalRegisters <= 10}">`

More on [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: Will apply this method. Thank you tmsbrndz

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied, please accept as answer.